# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException occurring while running junit tests

Tags: java, spring, junit

Here's the setup:

I'm unit testing an email notification service that I wrote using [Java Mail](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/) shown here:

```
@Service
public class EmailNotificationService implements NotificationService {
    @Autowired
    private CertificateService service;

    @Override
    public boolean sendFeedback(String title, String feedback) throws NotificationException {

    // Code here
    }
    @Override
    public boolean sendQuestion(String title, String question) throws NotificationException {

    // Code here
    }
}
```

My unit test class is as such:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"file:/service-commons/src/test/resources/service-commons.xml",
                   "file:/service-commons/src/test/resources/securityContext.xml",
                   "file:/service-commons/src/test/resources/mockUserProviderContext.xml" })
public class TestEmailNotificationService extends TestCase {

@Autowired
private EmailNotificationService emailServ;
@Resource
private WebApplicationContext context;

@Test
public void testSendFeedback() {
    try {
        boolean bool = emailServ.sendFeedback("feedbackTitle", "someFeedback");
        assertTrue(bool);
    } catch (NotificationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail();
    }
}

@Test
public void testSendQuestion() {
    try {
        boolean bool = emailServ.sendQuestion("questionTitle", "someQuestion");
        assertTrue(bool);
    } catch (NotificationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail();
    }
}
```

}

mockUserProviderContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="simpleCertService" class="service.commons.defaults.CertificateService" />
<bean id="service" class="service.commons.defaults.EmailNotificationService" />
```

I'm getting the following exception whenever I try to run this unit test:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'service': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:457)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:559)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305)
    ... 41 more
```

The CertificateService class:

```
public class CertificateService implements CertificateUserService {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SimpleCertificateService.class);

@Override
public User fetchUser(final X509Certificate certificate) {
    log.info("Fetching user for " + certificate.getSubjectDN().getName());
    return new SimpleUser(certificate.getSubjectDN().getName());
}

@Override
public User fetchUser(String name) {
    log.info("Fetching user for " + name);
    return new SimpleUser(name);
}

public class SimpleUser extends AbstractUser {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public SimplUser(String username) {
        super(username, "User", "thing", "User", "T1222", false);
        this.emailAddress = "some@example.com";
        this.phoneNumber = "(123)123-1234";
    }

    @Override
    public void clearCache() {
        super.clearCache();
    }

}
```

}

**Updated**

I realized that I was not importing  two context files, which I moved into src/test/resources, and are displayed here:

securityContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd
       ">

    <import resource="classpath:mongo-context.xml" />

    <!-- This html element specifies that we'll use annotation driven method 
        security throughout our application. -->
    <security:global-method-security
        secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <!-- This element is what protects the various service and UI end points. 
        It specifies we'll use an x509 filter to pull out the subject principal common 
        name and use that to produce a given User object. -->
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:csrf disabled="true" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
            requires-channel="https" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:x509 subject-principal-regex="(.*)"
            user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
    </security:http>

    <!-- This bean is the authentication manager we'll use. -->
    <beans:bean id="userAuthManager"
        class="service.commons.security.AuthenticationManager" />

    <!-- The bean is a UserDetails service that will provide the User object 
        for a given request. -->
    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService"
        class="service.commons.security.userDetailsService" />

    <!-- This is the UserFactory object that will fetch a User from the SecurityContext. -->
    <beans:bean class="service.commons.security.userFactory"
        id="userFactory" />

    <!-- This bean represents the session scoped User object. We use the 
        factory bean to fetch it from the SecurityContext and then scope it to a 
        session and make it available to the processing thread. -->
    <beans:bean scope="session" factory-bean="userFactory"
        factory-method="getUser" id="user" class="service.commons.security.User">
        <aop:scoped-proxy />
    </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="emailServ" class = "ral.service.commons.defaults.EmailNotificationService" />

    <!-- UserApplicationInfoService -->
    <beans:bean id="userInfoService"
        class="service.commons.user_info.UserApplicationInfoServiceImpl" />



</beans:beans>
```

service-commons.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


    <!-- Scan for components in the service-commons library... -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="service.commons"></context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

I then realized that I need to import another context file from another project into securityContext.xml to get access to certain beans that are missing.

The issue I'm having now is that when I run the tests, I get an IllegalStateException caused by a SAXParser exception with the following error message: 
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'import'. I tried changing my schemaLocation, adding the spring version, and tweaking the namespace, but I can't figure out why this SAXParserException keeps getting thrown. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried making the id of the service 'EmailNotificationService'?

Comment: Just tried it. No dice.

Comment: My application auto-discovers beans using this line in the config file - `<context:component-scan base-package="PACKAGE_NAME" />`. Try putting this in and removing the explicit bean definitions.

Comment: Just tried that, and got and IllegalStateException cause by a XmlBeanDefinitionException. It's saying that no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'

Comment: Done. Same issue as before. NoSuchBeanDefinitionException. This time it is displaying the bean type correctly though.

Comment: Sorry for so many edits, I have a cold I'm not paying attention. The last one should fix it though.

Comment: Can you try changing the initial part of your config to this? - `<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">`

Comment: Share the CertificateService class please and all mockUserProviderContext.xml file.

Comment: @EddúMeléndez, the certificate service has been posted above, and the mockUserProvidedContext.xml above is exhaustive.

Comment: There are one error in your logs which catch my attention. I'd like to see all your config. Error creating bean with name 'service': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}

Comment: Yeah that was a weird error. After I added the most recent edit from BugInTheCode, the type chenged from Java.Lang.String to service.commons.defaults.EmailNotificationService. There's really no other config for this Junit test. The only config the is the application context I provided above.

Answer (score 0):

Does `CertificateService` have a dependency that you aren't showing?

Also, the Spring junit runner normally creates a `GenericApplicationContext` rather than a `WebApplicationContext`. You need to add `@WebAppConfiguration` to create the latter.

Comment: No it doesn't. No spring dependency, if that's what you're referring to. Also, I added the WebAppConfig and the exception above is still thrown.

Comment: Sorry I missed this earlier, but you probably want to change `@Resource
private WebApplicationContext context;` to `@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;`.

Comment: Ok. Just changed that. The nested exception is the same, but the overall exception has changed from and IllegalStateException to a BeanCreationException. Before, spring was trying to inject an EmailNotificationService into the test class, but now it's trying to inject a TestEmailNotificationService and failing because it can't find the bean definition for EmailNotificationService.